# how to use sqlite3 in Xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: sql, xcode, macos, sqlite

how can I utilise the sqlite3.h from sqlite.org in my programs written in xCode 5.1.1?

One of the ways I was thinking was to download the precompiled binaries for Max OSX, http://www.sqlite.org, and then link them somehow to my files in my xCode-project.

How can I link these binaries to my project or xCode so that I can call upon the different sqlite3-functions?

Any help is much appreciated. I have OSX version 10.9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) way to use SQLite is to compile it statically into your program, i.e., just add the `sqlite3.c` file to your other source files.